# Map reference property fields to the same table as root class

Tags: sqlite, mapping, code-first, entity-framework-core

I have the model with reference properties

```
internal class AstronomycalBody : IAstronomycalBody
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Coord Coord { get; set; }

    public long Mass { get; set; }

    public double Speed { get; set; }

    public IAstronomycalBody CentralObject { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public long X { get; set; }

    public long Y { get; set; }

    public long Z { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use mapping like this

```
internal class AstronomycalBodyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AstronomycalBody> AstronomycalBody { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(DbSettings.ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AstronomycalBody>().Property(p => p.Coord.X).ForSqliteHasColumnName("CoordX");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AstronomycalBody>().Property(p => p.Coord.Y).ForSqliteHasColumnName("CoordY");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AstronomycalBody>().Property(p => p.Coord.Z).ForSqliteHasColumnName("CoordZ");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AstronomycalBody>().Property(p => p.CentralObject.Id).ForSqliteHasColumnName("CentralObjectId");
    }
}
```

to map the model on this table:

[image: AstronomycalBody Table]

Currently, the compiler is throwing this exception...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AstronomycalBody` is not a valid EF entity model class.

First, EF Core [does not support Complex/value types yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features), so the `Coord` member should be expanded in place.

Second, EF does not work with *interfaces*, so every navigation reference / collection element type should be entity *class*.

With that being said, not sure how your `IAstronomycalBody` looks like and how you can implement it (you might need *explicit* implementation of some members), but the entity class should be like this:

```
internal class AstronomycalBody //: IAstronomycalBody
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public Coord Coord { get; set; }
    public long CoordX { get; set; }
    public long CoordY { get; set; }
    public long CoordZ { get; set; }
    public long Mass { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public AstronomycalBody CentralObject { get; set; }
}
```

Now, since by convention it will generate the exact table shown, simply remove all shown lines in `OnModelCreating` and you are done.